# Cannot get setter method to work

Tags: ruby

I have a setter method that sets a month.  It needs to return a string '01'-'12'.  I want ti to be able to take number and text (both 3 didgit months and full months.  I am testing it by imputing Aug but cant get ti to work.  It is setting @month to the same as the imput (Aug).

The code is

```
def month=(month)
  # this can take a number or string, either with 3 char month or full month
  # it returns a 2 char string, left padded with 0s

  if !month.numeric?
    case month.upcase[0,3]
    when 'JAN'
      month = '01'
    when 'FEB'
      month = '02'
    when 'MAR'
      month = '03'
    when 'APR'
      month = '04'
    when 'MAY'
      month = '05'
    when 'JUN'
      month = '06'
    when 'JUL'
      month = '07'
    when 'AUG'
      month = '08'
    when 'SEP'
      month = '09'
    when 'OCT'
      month = '10'
    when 'NOV'
      month = '11'
    when 'DEC'
      month = '12'
    else
      month = '00'
    end
  end if
    @month=month.rjust( 2, '0' )
end
```

And I am calling it with

```
event.month = "Aug"
p event.month
```

Now here is the really freaky bit.  If I add a p line

```
            end if
            p month
            @month=month.rjust( 2, '0' )
    end
```

It prints "Aug" but the method works, with 'p event.month' returning '08' just after it is called

Any idea where I am doing wrong?

Ben

Comment: What is a "c character string"?

Comment: A typo , just changed it to string.  sorry

Comment: Have you considered using [Date](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) to get the month names? Way easier and let the OS take care of localizing...  Try `p Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES` and use that instead of 24 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have a conflict of names. You have local variable (method's argument `month`), and instance variable `@month` with setter `month=`. When collisions like those occurs, the most recent context is used. So the most recent context is `month` as a local variable, so you actually change not a class attribute, but a method's argument.

Just rename:

```
def month=(month)
```

to

```
def month=(m)
```

and everything will work.

Comment: OK, did not realize instance and local variables had to have different names.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, changed month to m but still getting same (wrong ) behavior.  Well slightly different, now if I include p month in method it return '08' and method reruns '08' but if I don't have the 'p month in method is returns 'Aug'

Comment: Correction, 
Ok, changed month to m but still getting same (wrong ) behavior.  Well slightly different, now if I include 'p month' in method it return '08' and method returns '08' but if I don't have the 'p month in method is returns 'Aug' (although 'p month' is method also returns '08'

Comment: Thanks for everyones help, you've been great, got it working.

Answer (score 3):

The line `end if` should just be `end`.

The presence of the trailing `if` means "don't run this case statement unless what follows is true", so your case statement only gets evaluated after you have already set the `@month` instance variable.

That is equivalent to it being

```
if @month=m.rjust(2, '0')
  if !month.numeric?
    case month.upcase[0,3]
    # when/else statements
    end
  end
end
```

So changing it to this:

```
end
@month=month.rjust(2, '0')
```

causes your code to work.

By adding your `p month` statement to debug, you cause that to be evaluated first, so the case statement runs (because `p` has a return value that is truthy), followed by the `@month` assignment, so your code runs in the correct order.

Playing around, I noticed that if you passed this a number instead of a numeric string, `.rjust` would fail, so I would suggest changing that to:

```
@month=month.to_s.rjust(2, '0')
```

And your `case` statement can be greatly simplified by saving the result of the `case`, rather than doing assignments in each `when`:

```
m = case month.upcase[0,3]
    when 'JAN' then '01'
    when 'FEB' then '02'
    #...
    else '00'
    end
```

Or, you could do this, to eliminate the case statement entirely like this:

```
def month=(m)
  if !m.numeric?
    m = Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES.index(m.capitalize[0,3])
  end
  @month = m.to_s.rjust(2, '0')
end
```

Comment: Oh, nice. Updated my simplified version with this suggestion.

Comment: LOL.  Thanks, I almost mentioned I was going to do it with a array.  %w and index.present? ? are new to me.  Also not heard the term truthy before;).

However ime still getting "Aug" being returned (using the second, most elegant code);(.

Comment: @BenEdwards I had `m.numeric?` instead of `!m.numeric?`. You must have  tried before I edited it.

Comment: hot sure how to put code in comments so put it https://pastebin.com/AjvRFnqZ.

I am getting a test.rb:9:in `month': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
        from test.rb:9:in `month'
        from test.rb:9:in `month'
        from test.rb:9:in `month'
         ... 11900 levels...
        from test.rb:9:in `month'
        from test.rb:9:in `month'
        from test.rb:9:in `month'
        from test.rb:25:in `<main>'

Comment: it should be `def month; @month; end` in your comment/pastebin above, otherwise you'll get a `SystemStackError`. Otherwise, it works!